# does FullCalendar 5 still allow for defining a custom dayName array?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Is it possible to define custom day names, short day names, month names etc. in FullCalendar version 5? I believe most of the localization is now done natively using javascript's `Intl` object. But I need to define latin names, which are not to be found in the `Intl` object. Can it be done with a custom **locale** file or maybe upon initialization of the calendar by passing in a property? From my tests neither of the two are working but maybe I'm just not doing it right?

```js
let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  dayMaxEvents: true,
  events: $events,
  locale: 'la',
  dayNames: ['Dies Solis','Dies Lunae','Dies Martis','Dies Mercurii','Dies Iovis','Dies Veneris','Dies Saturni'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Sol','Lun','Mart','Merc','Iov','Ven','Sat']
});
```

and the locale file `la.js` :

```js
FullCalendar.globalLocales.push(function () {
  'use strict';

  var la = {
    code: "la",
    week: {
      dow: 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
      doy: 4  // The week that contains Jan 4th is the first week of the year.
    },
    buttonText: {
      prev: "Prior",
      next: "Prox",
      today: "Hodie",
      month: "Mensis",
      week: "Hebdomada",
      day: "Dies",
      list: "Agenda"
    },
    weekText: "Hb",
    allDayText: "Tota die",
    moreLinkText: function(n) {
      return "+alii " + n;
    },
    noEventsText: "Rei gestae non sunt"
  };

  return la;

}());
```

(which I am loading via a script tag: `<script src='../lib/locales/la.js'></script>`).

Some things are picked up from the locale file, for example I see *hodie* instead of *today*.
I've tried defining `dayNames` and `dayNamesShort` in the locale file but doesn't seem to work either.